# what am i doing wrong trying to find element in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

I an trying to get an element by xpath that contains "Email Address" with the following:

```
driver.FindEIement(By.XPath(".//input[contains(@id,'Email')]"))
```

but get the error:

```
'no such element: Unable to locate element:
{"method":"xpath","selector":".//input[contains(@id,'Email')]"}
```

I have been following tutorial. but have got stuck.
can someone please point out what I am doing wrong,
I have just started with C#
the path for the element is

```
//*[@id='mG61Hd']/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input"
```

but changes position in a form hence the contains needed.
Please Help!
TIA

Comment: In order to diagnose this problem, we would need to see the text that contains the element you're trying to find.

Comment: Hi Robert it is a email field in a google form on a website, I can send to it with

.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='mG61Hd']/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).SendKeys(".FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='mG61Hd']/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).SendKeys("Johnny@gmail.com");
the html text is too big to post here but from the tutorial it should check all paths or am I mistaken
cheers for you quick response

Comment: Just post the HTML that contains the email.

Comment: For what it's worth, these kinds of deeply-nested X-paths are very difficult to get right.  You need software that tells you exactly what the X-Path is, but it's better if you can find an ID that's closer to the Email field, and then work inward from there.